# disable and enabling a html button

Tags: javascript, html, button

Users will only be able to click the submit button if users select a video file and the textbox is not empty. i can disable the submit button but i cant re-enable it

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file"><span></span></label>
<input type="file" name="videofile" id="videofile" />
<br/>
Please enter video title:
<br/>
<input type"text" name="videoTitle" />
<br />
<input type="button" disabled id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()"/>
</form>

                <script>

                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
                var n=document.getElementById('videoTitle').value;

                function submit();

                if($('#videofile')[0].files.length != 0) && (n.length > 1)
                {
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
                }
                </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your code had a lot of mistakes. This is your corrected code:

```
function check() {
  if (document.querySelector('#videofile').files.length != 0 && (document.getElementById("videoTitle").value.length > 1)) {
    document.getElementById('Submit').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('Submit').disabled = true;
  }
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qkpLenbe/)

- Missing ID added (u added only `name` attribute, and forgot the `ID` while still trying to use them)
- Changed 'submit' in code to 'Submit'
- Remove JQuery `$` syntax
- Validation on `keypress` rather than on submit click (which doesn't makes sense since u cant click the button while its disabled)
- `Else` code added to re-disable the button if conditions are not valid

Answer (score 1):

> `onclick` event over submit button does not make sense here. You must listen `change` event of the `file input` and `keyup` event of the `text input` and apply conditions accordingly. You have not assigned `id` attribute as well(`videoTitle`)

Also note that click handler will not be invoked if the button is `disabled`

Try this:

```js
 var submitBtn = document.getElementById('Submit');

 function enableDisable() {
   var elem = document.getElementById('videofile');
   var n = document.getElementById('videoTitle').value;
   if (elem.files.length && n) {
     submitBtn.disabled = false;
   } else {
     submitBtn.disabled = true;
   }
 }
```

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file"><span></span></label>
  <input type="file" name="videofile" id="videofile" onchange='enableDisable()' />
  <br/> Please enter video title:
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="videoTitle" id='videoTitle' onkeyup='enableDisable()' />
  <br />
  <input type="button" disabled id="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: just encounter some problem/errors using yr html code.. when posting the video file to the upload.php server i am getting Notice: Undefined index: file however when i use my original html form there is no error..

Comment: added screenshot of my code. cant paste it here as its too long.  Undefined index: error on line 4,9,11,13,17,18,19,20,21

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to make your `submit` function do something?

```
function submit() {
    if($('#videofile')[0].files.length != 0) && (n.length > 1) {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use change event for text and videofile elements. So that whenever you modify something, change event is triggered and ur condition is checked inside it. Submit button is enable according to it.

Se the below code for reference!

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file"><span></span></label>
    <input type="file" name="videofile" id="videofile" />
    <br/>
    Please enter video title:
    <br/>
    <input type"text" name="videoTitle" id="videoText"/>
    <br />
    <input type="button" disabled id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="submit()"/>
    </form>

                    <script>

                    document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
                    var n=document.getElementById('videoTitle').value;

                    function submit();

    $('#videofile').change(function() {
          if($('#videofile')[0].files.length != 0) && (n.length > 1) {
              document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
          } else {
              document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
          }
    });

    $('#videoText').change(function() {
          if($('#videofile')[0].files.length != 0) && (n.length > 1) {
              document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
          } else {
              document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
          }
    });

                    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is a bit simpler way to achieve this

```
<script>
    document.getElementById("submit").style.pointerEvents = "none"; //Disable
    var n=document.getElementById('videoTitle').value;

    function submit();

        if($('#videofile')[0].files.length != 0) && (n.length > 1)
        {
            document.getElementById("submit").style.pointerEvents = "all"; //Enable
        }
</script>
```

Just replace your script with this one & try..

Hope this works for you..